# multi thread programming - ACE_thread_t or ACE_Task

Tags: c++, multithreading, ace

I want to write a multi thread process (on linux) using ACE.
What is the difference between using ACE_Task and ACE_thread_t when implementing threads in c++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ACE_thread_t is really a low level handle. For implementing a multi threaded application using ACE implement a class that you derive from ACE_Task or ACE_Task_Base. See ACE_wrappers/examples/Threads or ACE_wrappers/tests for a lot of examples how to do this.